# Dispute tag synonym: [matlab-guide] -> [matlab]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

Since March [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) is a synonym for [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab), which does not make a lot of sense.

However there are currently 752 questions tagged with [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) and there was never a discussion here on Meta about merging it with the parent tag.

[matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) is an interactive GUI to create GUIs in Matlab and is heavily used to create user interfaces for scientific applications. Though it is possible to create a GUI without using GUIDE, the majority does and all GUI-related questions were tagged with [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) anyway. Now the tag is gone and we don't have any tag for marking this kind of questions anymore.

Though I would have subscribed to rename [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) to something more general like [matlab-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-gui), to have [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) is better than having no tag. So can we have it back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Makes sense. Synonym is now removed.